# Stuck on SqlDataReader.GetValues Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datareader

I am making a call to a SQL stored procedure which is returning a small table of users and their bosses. What I would like to do is compare this information against a variable in a different part of my application to enable/disbale editing of a GridView row. To accomplish this, it seems that the `GetValues` method would return what I need, which is the entire dataset the stored procedure is returning. My thikning is that once I have that data in my app, I could load that dataset into an array, and loop through it to do what I need to do.

The problem is this. In my code below I am getting the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'object'

When I look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on this method, the return value is an `int`.

My question is, since the stored procedure contains string data (user and boss names), why is the `GetValues` mehtod returning an `int`? How is my actual data represented as a number And how do I get my data into an string based array?

I've been looking at many examples and information on the internet, this seems to be a common problem new people have. I'm just not understanding or getting it, and I'm not making any progress. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    public Object[] GetDeptAppData()
    {
        Object[] myObject;
        string sp_deptapp, sp_status, sp_supervisor;

        //execute stored procedure to get data from database
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;

        cmd.CommandText = "SP_Admin_DeptApp_Load";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
        sqlConnection.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows == true)
        {
            //sp_deptapp = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
            //sp_status = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            //sp_supervisor = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();

            myObject = reader.GetValues(myObject);
        }
        else
        {
            //nothing in reader, throw exception
        }
        sqlConnection.Close();

        return myObject;
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error you encounter is located in this line:

```
myObject = reader.GetValues(myObject);
```

`myObject` is an array of objects and the `GetValues` method returns an integer that contains the count that is placed in the array. So in order to solve your error, you can change the line to the following:

```
var count = reader.GetValues(myObject);
```

Also, in your code, you only retrieve one row of data. This is - of course - fine if you only expect one row. When expecting multiple rows, you typically loop over the rows like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    // Read row and add row to list
}
```

For a sample on how to use SqlDataReader, see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

**Sample**

If you want to retrieve multiple rows and store the data, I suggest to add a class to store the data of a row (you might want to verify the data types so that they match the types that the SP returns):

```
public class Data
{
    public string DeptApp { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; } // this might be another data type
    public string Supervisor { get; set; }
}
```

Then retrieve the rows as follows:

```
public Data[] GetDeptAppData()
{
    //execute stored procedure to get data from database
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword"))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SP_Admin_DeptApp_Load";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (!reader.HasRows)
            {
                // throw exception
            }
            var lst = new List<Data>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var row = new Data();
                row.DeptApp = reader.GetString(0);
                row.Status = reader.GetString(1);
                row.Supervisor = reader.GetString(2);
                lst.Add(row);
            }
            return lst.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "myObject is an array of objects" - So is that ok? I was thinking myObject would be a single object that contained the results of the stored proc.

"GetValues method returns an integer that contains the count that is placed in the array." - So all it's doing is counting something? What is it counting, and why do I care? I don't really care how many rows are I the returned data from the stored proc, I care about the actual data.

It seems that the var COUNT will only contain a number representing how many items are in the stored proc.

Comment: @Rob: no, myObject is declared as `Object[]`, so it is an array of objects. A SqlDataReader is used to retrieve one row of data after another. GetValues stores the data in the parameter and returns the number of fields that was read from the current row (!). If you want to retrieve multiple rows, you need to add a loop. I'll extend my answer.

Comment: I had the WHILE lopp going before, but I didn't think I needed it because I was expecting the GetValues() to return all my data in one big shot to myObject

Comment: @Rob: I've updated the sample. Note that a SqlDataReader is a way to retrieve data quickly in a forward-only manner. It does return data row by row.

Comment: @Rob if you want all the operations in one command you may want to look in to `SqlDataAdapter`'s `Fill(` command. It will give you all of the results in one step and store the results in a `DataTable` or `DataSet` object.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, got busy on another work task. This worked perfect Markus, thank you! A few questions though if you're still around.
1. "public Data[] GetDeptAppData()" - Are we declaring a data type of DATA? Not sure the explanation of that keyword there

2. "var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()" - Not sure of the meaning/usage of VAR here. I did some reading here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx, not sure I get it though :)

The rest I get. We make a list and add items on a row by row basis. Then we kick it out as an array using the .ToArray method.

Thanks again!!

Comment: @Rob: good to hear that it helped. Data was just a sample name as I do not know the context of your project. No keyword whatsoever. You can use "var" to let the compiler determine the data type for you. So you can substitute var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() with SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(). The compiler knows that ExecuteReader returns a SqlDataReader and thus makes reader a variable of type SqlDataReader. Usually works very well, though in some very rare cases the compiler might not be able to identify the correct type.

Comment: @Markus, One last thing. How can I call this method and assign to a variable? I renamed the DATA[ to myData[] for my own readability.

I tried using "array[] myArray = Rob.GetDeptAppData();" but got an error saying it could not convert .myData[] to array[]. Since the new method is creating an array (return lst.ToArray), what is there to convert?

To say my question another way, how can I call the method and return the array into the calling method for use?

Comment: @Rob: either myData[] x = GetDeptAppData(); or var x = GetDeptAppData(); should work.

Comment: All done with this one, works great. Thank you again Markus! I owe you an internet beer :)

Answer (score 5):

[`GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an `int` which is *"The number of instances of Object in the array."*, so you cannot assign that to `myObject`. This is cryptic. It actually means (I believe) the number of column values returned for the current row.

You need:

```
int numColumnsRetrieved = reader.GetValues(myObject);
```

or something similar.

Your data is then present inside `myObject`, but only for the current row, as per the docs *"Populates an array of objects with the column values of the current row"*. So, you still need to iterate, such as:

```
var myObjectList = new List<object[]>(); // ... shudder ...
while (reader.Read())
{
    var myObject[] = new object[reader.FieldCount];
    int instances = reader.GetValues(myObject);
    myObjectList.Add(myObject);
}
```

You might find it useful to use a method that is more specific, such as [`GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var usersAndBosses = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    string username = reader.GetString(0); // column index 0
    string bossname = reader.GetString(1); // column index 1
    usersAndBosses.Add(Tuple.Create(username, bossname));
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want a spurious use for the return value from `GetValues`, you could flatten a table of strings into a list of strings:

```
var myStringList = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    var myObject[] = new object[100];
    int colCount = reader.GetValues(myObject);
    for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
    {
        myStringList.Add((string)myObject[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same question as I had for the other person who replied, why do I care about 'counting the instances of an object in the array'? I care about the data, not how much is there. A number doesn't do anything for me.


I like your second block, I have a similar thing in my code above commented out. I can identify, using while(reader.read()), the 3 unique columns of data, using reader.getValue(0).ToString(), but then I would just need to load it into an array, and then pass out of the method using RETURN.

Comment: First answer: I would steer clear of passing around arrays of objects, C# is a strongly typed language (even Tuples are lazy coding, although at least you can enforce type checking at compile time).

Comment: Second answer: If, for instance you pass in an object array of length 10, if there were only 3 columns it will tell you it only put 3 values into the array of length 10. I haven't ever found a use for it. `GetValues` is not designed to dump all rows and columns, no method is, so you need to iterate using `reader.Read()`

Answer (score 0):

Below there is ExecuteSelectQuery(...) function to get resuls of any SELECT queries.

The result of ExecuteSelectQuery is a list of arrays of System.Object elements which can be transformed to required types in calling code.

```
public sealed class DbPerformer
{
    private const string mySqlServerName = "localhost";
    private const string dataBaseName = "testdb";
    private const string uid = "login";
    private const string password = "password";

    private MySqlConnection connection;

    public DbPerformer()
    {
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "server=" + mySqlServerName + ";";
        connectionString += "Username=" + uid + ";";
        connectionString += "Password=" + password;

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Cannot connect to server {0}", mySqlServerName);
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Invalid username/password.");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool CloseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public List<object[]> ExecuteSelectQuery(string selectQuery)
    {
        List<object[]> resultList = new List<object[]>();

        if (true == this.OpenConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
            MySqlDataReader resultReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (resultReader.Read())
            {
                object[] resultRow = new object[resultReader.FieldCount];
                resultReader.GetValues(resultRow);
                resultList.Add(resultRow);
            }

            resultReader.Close();
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Can not open connection to database.");
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}
```